# In netsuite SuiteQL how do i see if a sales order has been invoiced?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

Does anyone know a way to check if a NetSuite Sales order, or sales order line item has been invoiced and / or the value of the Sales order that has veen invoiced?

I looked in Transaction and transactionLine and cant see anything. GPT isnt helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following query

```sql
select * from transaction where type = 'SalesOrd' and status in ('SalesOrd:G')
```

You can see all of the transaction statuses here: https://blog.prolecto.com/2013/08/30/netsuite-searchfilter-transaction-internal-status-list/